# MSI HDMI is not working

Tags: windows, usb, video, hdmi, windows-installer

so I bought a 2 monitor for my pc, the thing is that the hdmi in the msi part of my pc (where i connect the mouse, the keyboard and all the stuff) is not working...
I checked videos and entered in the bios manager, but the option to activate multiply monitor is not aviable.

Graphics card is the NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1060 3GB And the motherboard is: B450 GAMING PLUS (MS-7B86)

[image]
<sub>Click for full size</sub>

I decided to buy a connector that transforms an hdmi to 2 hdmi's but that only duplicates the screen, do not extends it.

Does anyone knows how to fix it? Or how to contact directly with msi so they can give me a solution?

NEW: BIOS panel

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

UPDATE: These are the ports from the graphics, I hope it helps (it uses a DP and only 1 HDMI port.
I can always buy an adapter for the DP or the DVI-d if this don't work.

[image]

Comment: Without knowing more details, there's nothing anyone can say right now. What's the motherboard? Does it have a graphics card [& which one, precisely]? AT least show us a picture of what you're trying to plug it into. BTW, you can't split one HDMI into two signals. It just doesn't work that way.

Comment: Answer is a placeholder based on the picture so far. If your GPU has its own dedicated outputs, you may be able to run another HDMI from there. The picture you uploaded only shows the motherboard's own outputs. The GPU may have its own, independant ports.

Comment: The CPU model is the MS-7B86. The thing is that one hdmi is connected to the motherboard and the other to the graphic card (the one that works)

Comment: We need to see a picture of the graphics card, then. BTW, the *motherboard* is MS-7B86. We have no idea what the CPU is, yet.

Comment: CPU is: AMD Ryzen 5 1600X Six-Core Processor, 3600 Mhz.
I also added more img's so you can see nothing appears in the section Integrated Graphics Configuration

Comment: That AMD doesn't have an APU as far as I can tell, so the motherboard's graphics output is likely inactive. I wanted to see a photo of any discrete graphics card you have installed… the 1060 you were talking about. The BIOS pictures don't help.

Comment: I shared a new IMG, those are the ports. How do I activate the hdmi input from the motherboard if the BIOS do not give me the option...

Answer (score 7):

After the addition of the GPU output panel…

What you appear to have are 1 DVI-D, one HDMI & 3 DisplayPort connectors.
It is unlikely that **all** those will work simultaneously, some will be shared, but it is very likely one of each type will work [& possibly two of the DisplayPort connectors].

So - you cannot directly connect two HDMI cables - there's nowhere to put them. Your earlier picture of the motherboard's video outputs are probably connected to nothing internally. They are designed for CPUs with onboard [APU] graphics, which your Ryzen 5 1600X doesn't have.

What remains to you are those direct connections from the PCI graphics card.

If either of your displays has a DisplayPort or DVI-D connector, then that is the obvious first choice. Buy a simple cable to match.
If they only have HDMI, then you will need a converter, from DVI-D or from DisplayPort, to HDMI.

---

Previous answer, before we had full details…

You cannot "split" HDMI into multiple independent signals. As you've discovered, a 'splitter' cable just duplicates the same image to two displays.

You will need to use a DVI-D cable to your other monitor, or get a DVI-D to HDMI converter if the display can't take DVI-D.

Comment: It should work with a cheap passive DVI-D to hdmi adapter, depending on use-case (probably not 4k resolution; movie content control may not work) as they hgave an overlapping specification and are electrically compatible. The DP ports on Nvidia cards are purportedly "dual-mode" which means the OP may be able to use passive adapter in that case also. I am surprised the card didn't come bundled with am DVI-HDMI adapter: the last 2 cards I got had one in the box.

Comment: @Yorik - We have yet to actually see the working outputs at all. All we have so far are the mobo outputs, probably connected to nothing. This answer is still based on that initial revelation & as noted in comments above, is still waiting for clarification.

Comment: he added photos. but your answer is correct, he needs an adapter. I was only extending the answer in that that a cheap passive one may be possible. The OP does not seem acquainted with the APU concept which adds to the confusion

Comment: The photos are of an app… all we need is a photo of the back-end of the graphics card… The original photo is of an output we now know cannot be functional.

Comment: I see a photo with 3 DP, one hdmi and a dvi-d in a double-wide PCI configuration

Comment: @Yorik - as of 15 minutes ago… which is what we were waiting for.

Comment: But I mean, the ports in the grapics works, the problem is in the port of the motherboard... The DP should work too but I need an adapter

Comment: The ports on the motherboard are not connected to anything, as I already mentioned in comments & my answer.